# HUGO: Insert JS in between markdown Content

Tags: javascript, markdown, hugo

I'm using a HUGO blog post template website and I want to modify one of my pages to have a JS calculator embedded into the content. Hence, I need to split the .Content variable somehow. Ideally I want it to look like this:

- HEADER
- Text block #1
- *JS Caculator*
- Text block #2
- Text block #3
- FOOTER

So far I managed to modify it such that the content comes first all in one big block and then the calculator. How do I split the calculator variable for this?

I found something like this before:

My attempt so far:

```
{{ define "main" }}

<section class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2 class="mb-4">{{.Title }}</h2>
        {{ .Content }}
        <br/><br/>
        <br/><br/>
        <br/><br/>
            <!-- Begin Scheidungskosten-Rechner von www.cool-funky-calculator.de -->
            <div id="s_r_de_calculator">
              <script type="text/javascript">
              </script>
              <script
                 type="text/javascript"
                 charset="utf-8"
                 src="https://www.cool-funky-calculator.de/widget/calculator.js">
              </script>
            </div>
            <br/><br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <br/><br/>
          <!-- </div> -->
        <!-- </form> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could write a custom [shortcode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/) for this. For example, write a shortcode named `js_calculator.html` in `/layouts/shortcodes/`:

Folder structure

```
Hugo Project
├── content
├── layouts
│   └── shortcodes
│      ├── js_calculator.html
├── static
├── themes
└──config.toml
```

Custom shortcode:

```html
<div id="s_r_de_calculator">        
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script
     type="text/javascript"
     charset="utf-8"
     src="https://www.cool-funky-calculator.de/widget/calculator.js">
  </script>
</div>
```

Then inside markdown files, use this like

```
## Your content

Some lines

{{< js_calculator >}}

More lines
```

Comment: your approach seems a lot neater. Will try it thank you!

Comment: OMG so easy! Thank you! You rock m8! First time I'm using HUGO that makes a lot more sense :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve this based on a similar problem I read before and splitting the Hugo .Content variable by the different headers in markdown:

Eg. this is splitting the text and inserting two js calculators in between the text:

```
{{ $paragraphs := split .Content "<h4 " }}
    {{ range $index, $p := $paragraphs }}
    {{ $pp := trim $p " \n" }}
      {{ if (eq $index 0) }}
        {{ printf "%s\n" $pp | safeHTML }}
      {{ end }}
      {{ if and (ne $pp "") (eq $index 1) }}
      <div class="boxtext">
        {{ printf "<h4 %s\n" $pp | safeHTML }}
        <br/><br/>
        <center>
      <div id="calculator_no1">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        </script>
        <script
           type="text/javascript"
           charset="utf-8"
           src="https://www.funky_calculator.com/widget/calc2.js">
        </script>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        <div id="js bit">
           <script>
           </script>
           <script
              type="text/javascript"
              charset="utf-8"
              src="https://www.cool-calculator/calc.js">
           </script>
        </div>
      </center>
      </div>{{ end }}
      <br/><br/>
      {{ if and (ne $pp "") (gt $index 1) }}
        <div>
          {{ printf "<h4 %s\n" $pp | safeHTML }}
        </div>
      {{end}}
    {{end}}
      </div>
```